# How to get MinTileRow, MaxTileRow with WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities

Tags: openlayers-3

I try to create a map from WMTS using the new optionsFromCapabilities function.

```
var result = parser.read(capabilitiesResponse);
var options = ol.source.WMTS.optionsFromCapabilities(result,
                    {layer: mapServiceName });
var WMTSsource =    new ol.source.WMTS(options)     
var myLayer =  new ol.layer.Tile({ source: WMTSsource});
var view = new ol.View({});

        map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        renderer: 'canvas',
        view: view,
        layers: [myLayer],

        });
```

In the following snipset from getCapabilities, the  TileMatrixLimits has MinTileRow and MaxTileRow for each level.

```
 <TileMatrixLimits>
                 <TileMatrix>EPSG:4326:6</TileMatrix>
                 <MinTileRow>6</MinTileRow>
                 <MaxTileRow>30</MaxTileRow>
                 <MinTileCol>17</MinTileCol>
                 <MaxTileCol>41</MaxTileCol>
     </TileMatrixLimits>
```

I would like to get those values (Min, Max )  in order to fit my first extent in a tile realy seen. How to get those value ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be supported currently unfortunately, see: https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/master/src/ol/source/wmtssource.js#L41

Also the format parser (src/ol/format/wmtscapabilitiesformat.js) is lacking support for this.

Feel free to open up a github issue, and pull requests welcome of course.

Comment: What alternative is there to set the tile range then?